# MiaCMS installation

Tags: php, content-management-system, installation

I'm trying to install MiaCMS all the installation steps are successful but at the end when i click on view site or administration button it redirects me to the specific url but its not displaying the the administrator interface or the site. Please help!

Comment: what url is it sending you to?

Comment: if i click on administration the url is  **localhost/MiaCMS/administrator/index.php** and if i click on view site it's **localhost/MiaCMS/index.php**

Comment: If  `localhost/MiaCMS/administrator/index.php`  does not work, you  try: 1) verify that the installer put the file were it is expected 2) Verify that you can serve a php page 3) try making a test.php page in the same directory to verify that you can hit it. 4) Check to see if  localhost/MiaCMS/administrator/index.php is trying to redirect you to a login page and failing

Comment: yes i can serve a test.php page from the same directory.The index.php contains the following code **$adminside =1; include('../index.php');** and the administrator directory also has index2.php and index3.php with code **$adminside =2; include('../index.php');** and **$adminside =3; include('../index.php');**

Comment: These topics may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271790/how-to-configure-php-to-display-detailed-errors-instead-of-error-500-page

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debugging in PHP for details see:

- [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)
- [How to configure PHP to display detailed errors instead of error 500 page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271790/how-to-configure-php-to-display-detailed-errors-instead-of-error-500-page)