# HTTP 500 / Configuration Error?

Tags: php, apache, lamp, system-administration

I am running a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.3 and followed [this guide](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486) to setup Apache, PHP (5.5.9), MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. The only other thing I did was enable mod_rewrite.

The problem I'm having is when executing PHP code that should return a warning or fatal error, it instead returns an HTTP error 500. For example, the following code works fine (as expected):

```
<?php
// convert fahrenheit to celsius
$temp = 80;
$temp -= 32;
$temp *= 5/9;
echo $temp;
```

Whereas I would expect the following code to return a PHP warning/error, but it instead returns a completely unhelpful HTTP error 500:

```
<?php
// convert fahrenheit to celsius
$temp = 80;
echo ($temp -= 32) *= 5/9;
```

What is going on and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: You may find you ARE getting a warning/error, but it's not being shown because you've got error notices set to not display on screen. Check your apache / error logs, or look up how to display PHP warnings and errors.

Comment: @Lee even after changing the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` value `error_reporting = E_ALL` (show all errors, warnings and notices) it still gives me an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: It will always give a 500 error, as this is the error that is occurring. Have you checked your logs?

Comment: Does this help maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: If you ini_set the display_errors and logs_errors in your php script, the parse error occurs before, so they are not set. Try putting the settings in the apache configuration.

Comment: @Lee Yes, you were right to mark this as a duplicate. I had to also change `display_errors = On` and restart the server again. Errors are displaying in the browser now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you're all sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to check your apache error logs , im sure they will tell you exactly what the 500 error is .

you could also check the error reporting in apache config/s to make sure the errors are set to report correctly

Comment: Technically, this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Lee: he cant comment due to repo..

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as comments say, you will/should find errors in your logs saying you have a parse error in your code on the `*=` part.

**Here is why**

The `($temp -= 32)` part of your code is OK, because the value `80-32` is set back to the `$temp` variable.
However the `*= 5/9` is not set back to a variable, but to the result of `($temp -= 32)` which is just a scalar value, this is why you have an error.

Just use it without the `=` sign to `echo` the result:

> echo ($temp -= 32) * 5/9;

Comment: I'm not asking how to fix the PHP error.

Comment: @mistermartin my bad. Check my comments then.