# IIS 8.5 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, oracle, iis

I spend a lot time to solve this problev, but I'm lost.

I have installed IIS 8.5, Oracle 12, PHP 5.6. In phpinfo(). oci8 set as "with".

When I'm load index.php with simple code as

```
<? echo 'hello world' ?>
```

All is good, the web page is available and it show me "hello .. ". ok.

I tried to connect to oracle. I used php documentation as example.

```
    $conn = oci_connect('...', '....', '...');
echo "2hello";
die();
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

And it show me the error 500.
How you can see, I try to debug and set die() function. So, page fall on the row with oci_connect. The row "2hello" don't print.

The funny think, that if i'm write echo before connect, it prints!

There is nothing in c:/interpub/logs
And nothing on error page in the IIS manager.

Maybe someone can help me here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: thanks, i forget about it