# AJAX - Insert html code into database

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am retrieving a html code from my website and I need to store it into a database. Code to retrieve looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("content-link2").onmousedown = function() {mousedown()};
document.getElementById("content-link2").onmouseup = function() {mouseup()};
function mousedown() {
   var code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    console.log(code2);
}
function mouseup() {
   var code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    console.log(code2);
}
```

And output is:

```
    <title>Template 1</title>
        <link href="http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <div class="logo">
        <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo">
    </div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;"><p>hlo</p></div>
<div id="comments">
<form name="forma">
<textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" class="refresh" cols="40" rows="5">Comments here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" id="send-data"><!--onClick="writeComment(e);"--> 
<div id="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true">
<p>This text can be by the user.</p>
</div>
</form></div>
```

I have started to do AJAX code which is saved in js file and it looks like:

```
 function updateDatabase(newCode)
            {

            // make an ajax request to a PHP file
            // on our site that will update the database
            // pass in our lat/lng as parameters
            $.post('http://localhost/fyproject/public/template2', {
                 _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
                 newCode: code2,
             }
            )
            .done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
            });
        }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('template2', 'BuilderController@postDB');
```

Controller:

```
     public function postDB(Request $request) {
        $newLat = $request->input('newCode');

        return "Is This Really Working? Oh by the way: newLat: $newLat";
    }
```

However I get this error in a console:

> POST http://localhost/fyproject/public/template2 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

Am I getting at the right track? What am I doing wrong here? If this is not good could I get a suggestion how to do this in another way?

Thank You

Comment: 500 error can mean anything. Try to see where your code fails by putting echo/print/dump statements in your `postDB` function. Don't have a lot of experience with AJAX, but your code looks pretty fine to me.

Comment: What happens if you attempt to visit that URL directly?

Comment: Check the server's error logs, turn on PHP error reporting, check any error trapping mechanism that Laravel uses, etc.  "500 Internal Server Error" means that there was an error server-side and it's not telling you what it is.  You need to find out what that error is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: I change code to redirect me to a same page so instead of "template2" I redirect to "template" and it gives me this error: POST http://localhost/fyproject/public/template 405 (Method Not Allowed)