# 500 Internal Server error during creating PDF Files using MPDF php

Tags: php, mpdf

i am using MPDF for generating Multiple PDF Files in PHP in a loop.
Some of PDF Files are so big for that purpose in a loop i have also define PHP functions for increase time limit etc.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");
set_time_limit(0);
```

But still it show me an 500 internal server error on server, works fine on local

Comment: on the error reporting and try what error it display

Comment: Check the PHP error log to see the reason.

Comment: Setting the memory limit to 50 GB is not a good solution, as this hides the real problem and leads to new problems (does the server have 50 GB of RAM? What if the script is called multiple times concurrently?)

Comment: @NicoHaase you are right and 50 GB just as an example.

Comment: i have turn error reporting also but it didn't show any error except 500 internal server error and this error for generating big files.@Barmar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er and find the PHP error causing the 500 status code. Unless you do that, we are not able to help.

Comment: check library path is correct  `require_once './vendor/autoload.php';`