# Variable text error 505 on page

Tags: php

I have a problem with the variable `$current`.  The problem is
I can't duplicate because of **error page 505**.

***Note***: I use this method because I need to change some numbers based on user updates.

```
<?php
    $current = " class billplzpost {

        var $variable;
        var $billplz;

        function __construct() {

            $this->variable = array();
            $this->billplz = new Billplz;
        }

        function apikey() {
            global $api_key;
            if ($api_key == 'APIKEY') {
                echo('You need to set up your API Key');
            } else {
                $this->variable['api_key'] = $api_key;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function collection() {
            global $collection_id;

            if (isset($_REQUEST['collection_id'])) {
                $this->variable['collection_id'] = $_REQUEST['collection_id'];
            } else {
                $this->variable['collection_id'] = $collection_id;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function name() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['nama'])) {
                $this->variable['name'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['nama'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                $this->variable['name'] = 'No Name';
                echo('You need to pass the parameter "nama"');
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function email() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
                $this->variable['email'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                if (!filter_var($this->variable['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                    //Nothing to do
                } else {
                    echo($_REQUEST['email'] . 'is not a valid email address');
                }
            } else {
                $this->variable['email'] = '';
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function mobile() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['telefonbimbit'])) {
                $this->variable['mobile'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['telefonbimbit'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                if ($this->variable['email'] = '') {
                    echo('You need to pass the parameter "telefonbimbit"');
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function amount() {

            global $amount;
            if ($amount == '') {
                if (isset($_REQUEST['amaun'])) {
                    $this->variable['amount'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['amaun'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                } else {
                    $this->variable['amount'] = '2';
                    echo('You need to pass the parameter "amaun"');
                }
            } else {
                $this->variable['amount'] = $amount;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function deliver() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['notifikasi'])) {
                $notification = filter_var($_REQUEST['notifikasi'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                if ($notification == 'ya') {
                    $this->variable['notifikasi'] = '3';
                } else if ($notification == 'email') {
                    $this->variable['notifikasi'] = '1';
                } else { //SMS
                    $this->variable['notifikasi'] = '2';
                }
            } else {
                $this->variable['notifikasi'] = '0';
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function reference_label_1() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['reference_label_1'])) {
                $this->variable['reference_label_1'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['reference_label_1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                $this->variable['reference_label_1'] = '';
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function reference_1() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['reference_1'])) {
                $this->variable['reference_1'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['reference_1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                $this->variable['reference_1'] = '';
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function reference_label_2() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['reference_label_2'])) {
                $this->variable['reference_label_2'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['reference_label_2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                $this->variable['reference_label_2'] = '';
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function reference_2() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['reference_2'])) {
                $this->variable['reference_2'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['reference_2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                $this->variable['reference_2'] = '';
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function description() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['description'])) {
                $this->variable['description'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            } else {
                $this->variable['description'] = 'No Description Provided';
                echo('You need to pass the parameter "description"');
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function redirect() {
            global $websiteurl;
            $this->variable['redirect_url'] = $websiteurl . 'verifytrans-$q.php';
            return $this;
        }

        function callback() {
            global $websiteurl;
            $this->variable['callback_url'] = $websiteurl . 'callback-$q.php';
            return $this;
        }

        function overrideSuccessPath() {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['successpath'])) {
                $this->variable['redirect_url'] = $this->variable['redirect_url'] . '?successpath=' . base64_encode(filter_var($_REQUEST['successpath'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
            } else {
                //Do Nothing
            }
            return $this;
        }

        function process() {
            global $websiteurl;
            global $fallbackurl;

            if (!empty($this->variable['reference_1'])) {
                $this->billplz->setReference_1($this->variable['reference_1']);
            }

            if (!empty($this->variable['reference_2'])) {
                $this->billplz->setReference_2($this->variable['reference_2']);
            }

            if (!empty($this->variable['reference_label_1'])) {
                $this->billplz->setReference_1_Label($this->variable['reference_label_1']);
            }

            if (!empty($this->variable['reference_label_2'])) {
                $this->billplz->setReference_2_Label($this->variable['reference_label_2']);
            }


            $this->billplz->setAmount($this->variable['amount'])
                    ->setCollection($this->variable['collection_id'])
                    ->setDeliver($this->variable['notifikasi'])
                    ->setDescription($this->variable['description'])
                    ->setEmail($this->variable['email'])
                    ->setMobile($this->variable['mobile'])
                    ->setName($this->variable['name'])
                    ->setPassbackURL($this->variable['callback_url'], $this->variable['redirect_url'])
                    ->create_bill($this->variable['api_key'], true);

            //If the Create Bills API NOT Successfully triggered
            if ($this->billplz->getURL() == '') {
                //If you have set the fallback url if the Create Bill API failed
                if ($fallbackurl != '') {
                    echo "<script>location.href = '" . $fallbackurl . "'</script>";
                }
                //If you have'nt set the fallback url, user will redirected to website url if Create Bill API failed
                else {
                    echo "<script>location.href = '" . $websiteurl . "'</script>";
                }
            }
            //If the Create Bills API Successfully triggered
            else {
                header('Location: ' . $this->billplz->getURL());
            }
        }

    }

    $call = new billplzpost;
    $call
            ->apikey()
            ->collection()
            ->name()
            ->email()
            ->mobile()
            ->amount()
            ->deliver()
            ->reference_label_1()
            ->reference_1()
            ->reference_label_2()
            ->reference_2()
            ->description()
            ->redirect()
            ->overrideSuccessPath()
            ->callback();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Include tracking code here
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $call->process(); ";
?>
```

And this is the script I use for ssh2. It working fine in other variables.

```
if (!($stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$con$remoteFile", 'w') |
array_unique(file("ssh2.sftp://$con$remoteFile", $current)) |
file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://$con$remoteFile", $current)
```

Comment: why are you storing PHP code in a variable? why are you passing that variable to `file()`?

Comment: not my script i just continue dev.. so i just need $current variable to work on that php code

Comment: look at line function redirect() { it change base on users id everything their update new file.. verifytrans-$q.php ( $q is variable for user id )

Comment: It won't... there are double quotes inside your long PHP code that are not escaped, some code inside the Long PHP code will be executed (and fail), that's probably why you get a 500 (500 not 505)

Comment: how about is just bypass this part?

`function collection() {
        global $collection_id;

        if (isset($_REQUEST['collection_id'])) {
            $this->variable['collection_id'] = $_REQUEST['collection_id'];
        } else {
            $this->variable['collection_id'] = $collection_id;
        }
        return $this;
    }`

Comment: Post your code in the question, and please add more details I don't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: check this line [link](https://jsfiddle.net/313wzr9n/) i just need to bypas error 500 this part

Comment: You need to see the errors that cause 500, check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687747/2595450