# Debugging 500 response in Chrome, I can no longer see the error message

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, google-chrome

Why is this happening?

I am trying to debug an AJAX call which is returning a 500 status.

When I click on the Preview and Response, I just get:

```
 message:"Server Error"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or has something changed?

Mick

Comment: share your code

Comment: If you get 500, your best bet is to take a look at laravel.log or apache/nginx logs.

Comment: What code would you like to see? I don't see that any code is relevant. The log says "Method [subscriptionsForAgreement] does not exist" which explains the error but not why I can't see it in Chrome?

Comment: The `server error` is returned from your webserver. Chrome is just showing up what it got from server. Hence the ideal place to debug this is in server. I guess you were expecting PHP error messages instead of the blunt message from apache/nginx

Comment: More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: But, I haven't changed anything on my webserver (Homestead) and it used to work.

Comment: Like @Kyslik said. Check your laravel .log file.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema I did that, you can read the result above. I don't want to know the error, I want to know why it does not get returned to Chrome.

Comment: @Mick Ah, my bad, for not understanding the question :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this to my .env file:

```
APP_DEBUG=true;
```

It's working now.