# Error when using PHP 7 with custom .ini files in Azure

Tags: php, azure, ini

I'm trying to make a custom .ini file to store sensitive information which I can then get using parse_ini_file. However I have some problems.

Using Azure I set up an Application Setting:

> Name: PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR Value: D:\home\site\ini

It shows that its loading my custom ini file in phpinfo which I named test.ini
Inside that I have...

```
[database_info]
;Database Information
dbUser=itstheuser
dbPassword=itsthepassword

[keys]
secretKey=aSeCreTKey
```

Then, in my php file I have

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('test.ini');
echo $ini['dbUser'];
```

However, this returned nothing, I tried an echo after this and that echoed fine, but the ini file did not.
**Note:** this was using PHP 5.6.

I then updated to PHP 7.0 and I get the error...

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

It seems PHP 7.0 does not like my custom ini file, because when I remove the ini file the error goes away and adding it back, brings back the error. I am unsure why this is.

So my problems are basically that I can't get my custom ini file to work, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` is for joining addition *PHP* configuration. It will not load unknown sections or directives (it's for php modules and their zend_parse_ini declarations). Hence `parse_ini_file` should be given the full path to the `test.ini`. Enable error_display, or look into log files. There should be a warning of sorts I'd presume.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: Mine says D:\local\Config\PHP-7.0.30\php.ini 
So how do i access it if that file doesnt exist for me to access

Comment: Your `php.ini` is not really relevant. `parse_ini_file()` works independently of PHPs main configuration. Also you should really look for the real error message first.

Comment: I assume I'm meant to be looking in the php_errors.log file, but in there are no errors relating to this issue, just basic errors like incorrect syntax when I was building it.