# how to show errors instead of HTTP ERROR 500 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My CI project doesnt show any error and it is only show HTTP ERROR 500.
I have searched already and done these:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

    case 'development':
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    ini_set("error_reporting","E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT");
    break;
```

Also tested

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But nothing changed.
Any help would be apriciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: No, that post did not help me!!

Comment: Have you `switch` that used `case`?

Comment: Yes, that is part of my code. the case is running but the errors are still hidden.

Comment: Have you checked your web servers error log? I would also recommend not to just include a small snippet of your code (like the `case` without showing the `switch` since we won't know if you've missed something or are simply not showing us all the code).

Comment: You also don't need to use both `error_reporting()` and `ini_set('error_reporting', ...)`  since they set the same setting.

Comment: Maybe you can't change ini file content. After using `ini_set()` use `ini_get('display_errors')` to check value of `display_errors`

Comment: used ini_get('display_errors') and it returns "On" , but errors are hidden and error 500 is showing!

Comment: @Majid.r Maybe error is for codes before `ini_set()`

Comment: No , ini_set is in index.php and my code is in some controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before.
this problem occurs because I deleted the `errors` folder in`application / view` codeigniter.

the solution is only to download the folder back on the [codeigniter web](http://codeigniter.com)

Comment: Thanks, But No! I already have this folder in my prroject. also i have to mention that i only have this problem in my host!, in localhost everthing is ok.