# How to fix 500 error only when trying to login to wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

When i try to login to the wordpress admin panel it throws 500 error. But the website i.e, the front end works fine. I tried to deactivate all the plugins via FTP and checked the admin panel working fine, at the same time the website shows Blank white page. Even if the admin is logged in not able to access the menu such as pages etc. I understand there is some problem with the plugins but not able to sort out the problem precisely. Please someone give me a hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: try deactivating them and reactivating one by one

Comment: [maybe wordpress can help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=500+admin+panel)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Vishwa. When i deactivate all the plugins the website is showing only a white page.

Comment: Activate all the plugins and in your php.ini file enable display_errors. It will give you an error and the file/line the error relates to. Then post it here if you need help fixing it.

Comment: The admin panel is working now. But some menus are not opening and shows 500. For example if i click on "Pages" it loads for sometime and shows page not found and sometimes 500 error. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by the woocommerce plugin.
I deactivated the plugin and installed a lower version and the admin panel works fine.