# Unable to get username availability using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get username availability using `ajax` and `PDO` from `SQL` this works in `localhost` but when I host it I get bellow error.
[image]

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#username").keyup(function () {
                var username = $(this).val();
                if (username.length > 3) {
                    $("#ucheck").show();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: './include/namecheck.php',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            $("#result").html(data);
                            $("#ucheck").hide();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                } else
                {
                    $("#result").html('');
                    $("#ucheck").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php
                                    if (isset($error)) {
                                        echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username");
                                    }
                                    ?>" tabindex="1" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" id="username" required autocomplete="off">
```

**PHP**

```
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/include/config.php");
if ($_POST) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username=:name");
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "<small class='text-danger form-text'>Username already taken !</small>";
    } else {
        echo "<small class='text-success form-text'>Available</small>";
    }
}
```

and the `namecheck.php` is located `http://safebrowser.tk/include/namecheck.php` and why do I get an error.

Can someone help me sort what wrong in the code?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are some error on your PHP page, try to get the error, by checking the `Network` tab in developer tools of Browser by pressing `F12` key

Comment: @harishsharma i have added error in question as a image https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlJjj.png

Comment: That error is not in under `Network` tab,

Comment: @harishsharma i checked in `console` tab if its wrong where do i need to check

Comment: what are the contents of that config.php file? The other PHP there is OK

Comment: check under network tab, and there will be XHR,  and you ajax call will be in red font

Comment: @AhmedSunny here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/sln4V.png

Comment: @RamRaider `config` works fine

Comment: click on the x on right corner of the screen, 2nd one/ bottom one. your network tab is hidden behind it

Comment: Have you shown the full contents of namecheck.php?

Comment: @RamRaider yes thats the content of it.

Comment: is your $conn defined properly? may the $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/ is wrong

Comment: @AhmedSunny here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulBJ.png

Comment: please take a screenshot like [this](https://imgur.com/a/cg9mNrM)

Comment: you need to do some debugging for this because it looks OK ~ put some exit points in there and see where it breaks - or, better - check the error log

Comment: @AhmedSunny here https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrpQI.png for more error report vist this demo page http://safebrowser.tk/register.php

Comment: @RamRaider i tried this earlier  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er it doesn't work this error is at script.

Comment: Have you looked at the Apache Error logfile?