# PHP ContactForm

Tags: php, html

I cant seem to figure out what the problem is with my code. After pressing submit it will redirect to a error page and says "This page isn’t working website is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <form action="contact.php" method="POST" class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jane Doe" tabindex="1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane@doe.com" tabindex="2" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Hello There!" tabindex="3" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" cols="50" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message..." tabindex="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Send Message!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
   $message_sent = false;
    if(isset($_POST['email]') && $_POST['email'] != ''){

        if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){

            $userName = $_POST['name'];
        $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $messgeSubject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    
        $to = "email"
        $body = "";
    
        $body .= "From: ".$userName. "\r\n";
        $body .= "Email: ".$userEmail. "\r\n";
        $body .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";
    
        mail($to,$messgeSubject,$body);

        $message_sent = true;

        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `isset($_POST['email]')` should be `isset($_POST['email'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Answer (score 1):

there is an typing error in your php (line no 3).. you have written

```
isset($_POST['email]'
```

it should be

```
isset($_POST['email'])
```