# How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error NGINX + PHP7

Tags: php, nginx

So, I have 500 error on a page and I want more information why I do have error (because the page works fine in local but not on my server)

I try the following solution preconised in [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er) but it doesn't help. I restarted nginx everytime and no changes.

Here is the folder on my server (VPS, no cPanel) :

[image: folder]

here is my actual state of php.ini :

http://pastebin.fr/75379

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you placed at the top of your PHP.INI file is what you would use in an actual .php file to turn on error reporting / show errors on a per file bases. You do not add that to your PHP.INI file.

Example of use in a .php file:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

If you search your PHP.INI file you will find `error_reporting = E_ALL`, and `display_errors = On` are set.

Notice the definitions in the PHP.INI file:

```
; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; For production environments, we recommend logging errors rather than
; sending them to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On
```

You should not display errors in a production environment. You don't want to reveal any extra information to any potential hackers. Also these errors will mean nothing to your users. You should just show a generic error page and log all your errors for your review.

In a development environment I would have them all on and `display_startup_errors = On`.

I see `log_errors = On` so you should be getting your error messages logged to:
`/var/log/nginx/default-error.log`. I suggest looking there to find your issue after you fix your PHP.INI file.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't get the <?php stuff that 's why I was block altough it makes sense now

Comment: and yeah I'm always display error shouldnt be display in production env of course, but it's a small and private website anyway. Tryed by the log but seems unreadable. Also I don't have the default-error.log, just error.log

https://imgur.com/a/7PzaMzJ