# Blank response no values displaying json php

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb

So the implementation is as follows , I include the database , which I know that it works , cause I had an or die (" can't connect to database ") which never prompts, so the root can connect to the db. I have a header for utf-8 decoding , but it did not work apparently.
And when I echo json it returns nothing , just blank.
Note: I use mariadb.
Also the error reporting is set to On and I don't get any error.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: 
charset=utf-8');
include('db_connect.php');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1");

$stmt ->execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($val1col1, $val2col2, $val3col3);

$values = array();

while($stmt ->fetch()){

   $temp = array();

   $temp['col1'] = $val1col1;
   $temp['col2'] =$val2col2;
   $temp['col3'] = $val3col3;

   array_push($values,$temp);
}

echo json_encode($values, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

?>
```

Comment: `json_encode()` only takes 3 arguments, you're giving 4 arguments.

Comment: `json_encode($values, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, 512);`

Comment: And you don't need the `512` argument. Your data is not nested deeply enough that you need to specify the limit.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your assistant, I change it to json_encode ($values); but still it's blank with no results on the screen.

Comment: I also tried with only $values, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE  but still nothing

Comment: Do you see any errors in the DevTools console?

Comment: Also check the Network tab of DevTools to see the raw response.

Comment: Yea it seems I got an error appears there it says exactly "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error) Note : that all this things I'm running the on localhost for testing.

Comment: On db_connect.php I'm not getting any error though

Comment: [how to diagnose 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: Well I am really stupid, it seems that there was an extra line in the php.ini where should be commented out , it was errors display off. Anyway now I can't see the error , thank you!!! I will report back with a way to fix it the error appears to be on line 3 and 8 of this file

Comment: It is a fatal error to a member function execute() on bool

Comment: That means `prepare()` is getting an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: Well it seems you where right it was on the name of a column , this error was so silly , I had a column named Number , and I called it Name in the prepare....THANK YOUUUUU