# IIS HTTP-Fehler 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, iis

Hello i try to install a PHP mvc Website in IIS but i just getting this error:

HTTP-Fehler 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the associated configuration information for the page is invalid.

Detailed error information:
IIS Web Core module
Notification BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error code 0x8007000d
Configuration error
Configuration file \? \ C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ public \ web.config
Requested URL http: // localhost: 80 / public /
Physical path C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ public 
Login method Not yet determined
User login Not yet determined

Configuration source:
-1:
0:

Additional Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the web server or web application. In certain cases you can find more information about the cause of this error in the event logs.
Show more information »

What could be the problem? IIS settings? Unfortunately I don't know what to do next.

Comment: SO is English-only. You need to translate your post.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: Run a report and the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem:

1. To check whether URL rewrite is installed, if not, you can install it from this link: [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
2. HTTP Error 500.19 and 0x8007000d says about invalid element in your web.config. That's why IIS cannnot read this file for start your site. You can find probloem element by commenting some blocks and looking for type of error. For example, make a backup for your web.config first, then remove the rewrite section and test. If the problem persists, remove the httpErrors section, and so on. If the pages shows correctly after you remove one section, then the problem is with that section. You need double check what's wrong with the section and update the correct configuration.