# Old Laravel project is not working after a while, What can I do to make it running again?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an old project and I am not the person that worked on it

I need to run it again but it's giving me this error

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I tried to run `composer update` but it gives me this error

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires php ^7.1.3 but your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev].
```

Comment: Did you check your Laravel, PHP, Apache logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: DO this for the first error: php": "^7.1.3|^8.0",

Answer (score 0):

You can do composer install by following command
 `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-script`

Also another way can be to update your composer.json php version to 8 or downgrade your system php version to php7.

Hope it works.