# Get email from html form and delete it in database inphp

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I'm student and I'm new to php and mysql. Please help me with this.
Can you correct these codes and help me with your answers.
This is my html form :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Subscribe
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="delete-subs.php">
Email:<input type="Text" id="semail" name="semail"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="delete">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is delete-subs.php :

```
<html>
 
<head>
   <title>Delete subscribe</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <center>
        <?php
 include'db/config.php';
        $semail = $_REQUEST['semail'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM sbscribers WHERE semail=$email";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "<h1 style='color: red;'>Thank you</h1><br>Successfully deleted.";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
        ?>
    </center>
</body>
```

When I click the button nothing appears, no errors and nothing; please help me.

Comment: Warning your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: Using a prepared statement will also fix the problem, which is that you forgot to put quotes around `$email` in the SQL.

Comment: If you don't see anything, neither the sucess message or the SQL error, there must be a syntax error in the script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: Add `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` to the very top of your page .. This will display all warnings, notices and fatal errors for troubleshooting.