# Added define('cookie_domain', $_server['http_host']) to wp-config file and now its broke

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have created a multisite wordpress and was trying was routing custom domains for each subsite.
The domain mapping was working and I read about adding
`define('cookie_domain', $_server['http_host']);`
to wp-config. I added it and then everything came down. So I removed it from wp-config and it is still down. Does anyone know if this made changes elsewhere that I need to edit? I am getting status 500 when I try to access the site.

Any help really appreciated. Stressing big time
Thanks

EDIT :

I checked the logs and the date time aren't correct so not sure if it's the error that causing the site to be down?

`Server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

````
Cannot serve directory /home/{name}/domains/{domainname}.com/public_html/.well-known/:
 No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.htm,index.shtml,index.php,index.phtml,index.php,
index.html) found, 
and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: www.google.com```
````

Comment: PHP is case-sensitive - `$_server` [should be $_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).  `500` is the generic response shown to the world, it deliberately does not give any details so as not to leak any sensitve info.  But your web server and/or PHP logs will tell you exactly what the problem is.  Start there.

Comment: Incorrect date and time suggest they are errors from another date/time. At least the last error (`No matching DirectoryIndex`) seems to have been generated when someone arrived on your site from a Google link, so probably not you now troubleshooting and hitting reload?  If you don't think you're seeing errors, maybe you need to enable them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er