# Localhost is okay but once deploy, my php website is not working

Tags: php, ajax, email, resend.com

My website is PHP website.
My website is working well with localhost. Ngrok sever is too no problem,
but I deployed it in dash.infinity.com.
Of course, there is not any mistake,
but website is not working well.
I used resend API as email API, it occurred internal server error 500.
Please help me.
My code is following.
This is ajax part.

```
function finish_exam() {
                    $("#ring").addClass("ring");
                    $("#ring").html('Saving');
                    $("#loading").addClass("loading");
                    $('body').css('background-color', '#959566');
                    // var question_array = [];
                    // console.log(q.length);
                    // console.log(q)
                    // console.log(question_array);
                    // console.log(question_array);
                    // console.log(data);
                    $.post('test_insert.php', {
                            email: "<?= $email ?>",
                            title_arr: array2json(title_arr),
                            answer_arr: array2json(answer_arr),
                            q: array2json(q),
                            name_arr: array2json(name_arr),
                            all_answer_arr: array2json(all_answer_arr),
                            question_type: array2json(question_type),
                            // data: data
                        },
                        function (returnedData) {
                            if (returnedData) {
                                console.log(returnedData);
                                let answer = JSON.parse(returnedData);
                                if(answer.flag == "success") {
                                    exam_number = answer.exam_no;
                                    $("#ring").removeClass("ring");
                                    $("#ring").html('');
                                    $("#loading").removeClass("loading");
                                    $('body').css('background-color', '#ffffcc');
                                    // $("#export_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    
                                    $.post('gmail_api.php', {
                                        email:"<?= $email ?>"
                                    }, function (returnedData) {
                                        if(returnedData) {
                                            console.log(returnedData)
                                            alert("Survey completed, no further action is necessary on your part.");
                                        }
                                    } ) 

                                }
                            }
                        }).fail(function () {
                        console.log("error");
                    });
                }
```

This is PHP part:

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
try {
    // Initialize the Resend client
    $resend = Resend::client('re_SN6U9cej_iLHNvbmjwgGCQEjyCQqiKtsL');

    // Prepare the email data
    $emailData = [
        'from' => 'Survey Notification <onboarding@resend.dev>',
        'to' => ['appnotificationagent@gmail.com'],
        'subject' => 'Survey project notification',
        'text' => $email . ' sucessfully completed their survey.',
        'attachments' => [
            // [
            //     'filename' => 'invoice.pdf',
            //     'content' => $invoiceBuffer
            // ]
        ],
        'headers' => [
            // 'X-Entity-Ref-ID' => '123456789',
        ],
        'tags' => [
            // [
            //     'name' => 'category',
            //     'value' => 'confirm_email',
            // ],
        ],
    ];

    // Send the email
    $resend->emails->send($emailData);

    echo "success";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

As I know, code is no problem.
I think Resend API server is not accept my domain.
How to solve it?
Or Is there other email API without error when deploy my web site?

> 500 internal service error

Comment: Check the webserver error log to see what could be causing the 500.

Comment: Did you copy the vendor code to the server?  Just guessing. Not much info.

Comment: Yes, I copied vendor code in my server.

Comment: Go check the php error log on the server to get the exact error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.
My php website is supported php version 8.2.
But my hosting site is supported the php version 7.4.
There is a reason.
Thank you for your time.