# Hello guys i have problem in my code i want upload multiple image using dropzone lib and it doesn't uploaded in database or storage in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

my uploade Images controller

```
use App\Models\ProductImg;

class MutliImageController extends Controller
{
    public function fileStore(Request $request){
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->storeAs('public/images/products/gallery',$imageName);

        $imageUpload = new ProductImg();
        $imageUpload->img = $imageName;
        $imageUpload->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>$imageName]);
    }
}
```

html blade

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.0/dropzone.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.2/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.0/dropzone.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="{{route('dashboard.products.uploadMultiImg')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
    @csrf
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.dropzone =
        {
            maxFilesize: 12,
            renameFile: function(file) {
                var dt = new Date();
                var time = dt.getTime();
                return time+file.name;
            },
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(file, response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(file, response){
                return false;
            }
        };
</script>
```

model Code

```
class ProductImg extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'product_img';
    protected $fillable=['product_color_sizes_id','img','file','product_id'];
}
```

route file

```
Route::post('products/add/multiImg', [MutliImageController::class, 'fileStore'])->name('dashboard.products.uploadMultiImg');
```

console erorr

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/products/add/multiImg 500 (Internal Server Error)

I tried and searched a lot and did not find a solution

Comment: The first step of debugging is to check the logs.  `500` is a generic error response shown to the world, it deliberately does not give any details so as not to leak any sensitve info. Your Laravel/web server/PHP logs will tell you exactly what the problem is.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: ok , thank you very much

Comment: should i give you my example, 
ihave uploaded many images via dropzone, spatie media library in the backend.