# PHP 8.2 locally on apple mac M3 throws 503 with a simple pg_sql pdo connection string

Tags: php, pdo, psql, apple-silicon

This simple connection string test causes 503 error

```
try{
    $dsn = "pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=skeleton;";
//    $dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=nis;";
    // make a database connection
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'symfony', 'symfony', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    if ($pdo) {
        echo "Connected to the skeleton database successfully!";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    var_dump($ex);
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
}
```

I've got two brew systems, one for the apple silicon chip services and one for the intel chip services (with rosetta)

PHP is installed with the intel chip brew, postgresql@13 also but every test throws a 503 error

The simple connection test with mysql works even if mariadb is installed with the other brew.

I've tried everything that i could, i can connect to psql in command line but with php, i can't, the PDO is correctly enabled (by default BTW)

Comment: Have you installed the PDO PostGreSQL driver?

Comment: how is the 503 related to this code ? does this work at the cli ? Is your apache intel or apple silicon ? is the php libphp.so of apache for the same chipset ? etc...  The only way i could get apache to serve both 8.2(apple) and 7.4(intel) is via php-fpm ,  one on port 9082 and the other on 9074.

Comment: @Barmar it is installed by default, i see it's installed when id throw phpinfo();

Comment: Check the PHP error log to see the specific error message. We can't tell what's wrong just from a 503 error.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg apache is on the same chipset yes. The libphp.so is provided by httpd that is installed on this chipset, on cli if i make ```php -i |grep pdo``` or if i make a phpinfo() i see pdo pgsql is installed

Comment: @Barmar there isn't php log, only httpd logs that only contains general 503 message:

```[Wed Jan 10 21:41:34.762219 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9904] [client 127.0.0.1:58733] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Wed Jan 10 21:41:34.762940 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9904] (54)Connection reset by peer: [client 127.0.0.1:58733] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: @Barmar error_display is on but there's nothing helping in log files

Comment: 503 errors don't happen by themselves. PHP must be getting an error that it can report. What happens if you run the script from the CLI instead of the webserver?