Call to API Endpoint Successful but DevTools Showing 500 Error
I'm using Laravel to make a request to an endpoint, which when I test locally works fine and returns what I'm expecting to the frontend, and even when I access the API route/Request URL in the browser it returns the proper response I see in the frontend (ex. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeRequest?user_input=salmon%2Crice returns a perfectly fine response). However, when I open DevTools it tells me I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error. What's wrong with my configuration?
api.php:
Route::post('/makeRequest', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'makeRequest'])->name('makeRequest.store');
Route::get('/makeRequest', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'makeRequest'])->name('makeRequest.store');

form in my view:
<form id="recipeForm" method="post" action="/makeRequest">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" id="ingredientInput" placeholder="Ingredient" class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs">
</form>

makeRequest function:
function makeRequest(ingredients) {
    if (ingredients.length > 0) {
        var userInput = ingredients;
        var url = `/api/makeRequest?user_input=${encodeURIComponent(
            userInput
        )}`;
        console.log(ingredients);

        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ingredients: ingredients }),
        })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((html) => {
                handleApiResponse(html);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    } else {
        alert("Please add at least one ingredient before submitting.");
    }
}

edit: adding a screenshot from Network tab in DevTools


What do your server-side logs say about the 500 error?

@Phil Hi, would these be the same ones found in ./storage/logs?

@dejsdukes yes.

@francisco there's nothing about a 500 error when I check the logs

Does the error come from the post request?

Please show dev tools network tab screenshot with selected failed request info and response tabs

@morgan9999 yes the error is from the post request

Could it be that your log file has the wrong permissions?

U can try the API via postman, https://www.postman.com/downloads/. Because sometimes DevTools not show correctly, 500 error

How are you submitting the form, and how are you calling the Javascript makeRequest() function?  Also, 500 is a generic error response shown to the world, it deliberately does not give any details so as not to leak any sensitve info. Your web server and/or PHP logs will tell you exactly what the problem is.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

The JS makeRequest() does not seem to include the CSRF token, unless you are adding it some other way?

If the error come from post request it might be because CSRF token is not added,
Try to add 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') in the header

@dejsdukes use 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') because @csrf is in <meta> tag link.

You need to add csrf token to your POST request, modify your makeRequest to
function makeRequest(ingredients) {
    if (ingredients.length > 0) {
        var userInput = ingredients;
        var url = `/api/makeRequest?user_input=${encodeURIComponent(
            userInput
        )}`;
        console.log(ingredients);

        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ingredients: ingredients }),
        })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((html) => {
                handleApiResponse(html);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    } else {
        alert("Please add at least one ingredient before submitting.");
    }
}


the best way to solve this problem is if you have the parameters of API or you know where you have to get data you can pass data through the gate request that will help you to solve this problem but before this, if you want to return data in Jason so you also need to done view in Jason the problem here you have to define in your route
<form id="recipeForm" method="post" action="makeRequest.store">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" id="ingredientInput" placeholder="Ingredient" class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs">
</form>

public function store(Request $request)
\\...

