Why is my assertion test returning an error status of 500 instead of supposed 200 on resource update [PUT] request?
I'm new to php and I'm trying to build a crud todolist application.
I'm having it easy thanks to Laravel's great accessibility, but I got stuck on a small problem.
I'm trying to update a "todo" array to my endpoint here at :
Route::put("/todos/{user}/{id}", [TodoController::class, "update"])->middleware(["auth", "verified"])->name("todo.update");

The endpoint above receives a $user and $id parameters in the requests, which are handled in the update controller
public function update(Request $request, $user, $id)
    {
        $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);

        if ($user->id != $todo->user_id) {
            return response()->json([
                "error" => $todo->errors()->first(),
            ], 400);
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "text" => ["required", "string"],
            "user_id" => ["required", "integer", "string"],
            "isDone" => ["required", "integer", "boolean", "string"],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                "error" => $validator->errors()->first(),
            ], 400);
        }

        $requestData = $request->only(["text", "isDone"]);

        return response()->json(Todo::edit($id, $requestData), 200);
    }

and finally arriving at the final destination of its model method edit here
public static function edit($id, $data)
    {
        return self::where("id", $id)->update($data);
    }

I made a TodoControllerTest.php specifically to test controllers, and in my test here I'm sending the id of the todo, and the id of the user user_id, as well as the array $requestData to be updated.
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Todo;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;


class TodoControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_authenticated_user_can_update_todo()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $todo = Todo::factory()->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);

        $updatedData = [
            "text" => "updated todo text",
            "isDone" => true
        ];

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->put(route('todo.update', ['user' => $user->id, 'id' => $todo->id]), $updatedData);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $this->assertDatabaseHas("todos", $updatedData);
    }
}


?>

This is the output I get from the test
  FAILED  Tests\Feature\TodoControllerTest > authenticated user can update todo
  Expected response status code [200] but received 500.
Failed asserting that 500 is identical to 200.


Have you tried updating yourself, in a browser?  500 is a generic error response shown to the world, it deliberately does not give any details so as not to leak any sensitve info. Your web server and/or PHP logs will tell you more about what the problem is.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

*webserver and/or PHP, and Laravel logs will tell you more.  One observation - are your validation rules really valid?  How can a user_id be both an integer and a sting?  Or isDone be an integer, a bool and a string?  BTW you are already using route-model binding for $user in the route, you could do the same for your todo, ie Route::put("/todos/{user}/{todo}", and public function update(Request $request, $user, $todo), then you don't need to findOrFail() your todo.
